# Cannot install and activate contrib themes in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, installation

On my XAMPP D8-beta15, I cannot seem to use any of the contributed theme modules. What I did was to

- download and unpack it in the theme/contrib folder
- go to /admin/appearance
- click on "install and set as default"

Regardless of which theme I install, when I go back to the main site, I get a plain HTML view with no style sheets in <head> and no HTML title.

Same result if I install the themes in folder sites/all/themes. There are neither error messages nor log messages.

What am I missing? Could this be a server issue?

Comment: I've tried mayo, zircon, gratis and adaptivetheme so far.

Comment: OK, so apparently, this was due to a broken Drupal installation. I set up a new Drupal installation with a clean database and Mayo worked out of the box. Sorry for the confusion.